# Client side code to server side code

Tags: javascript, php

Is this possible, for example if I have a Javascript code which is client side scripting and I want to convert it to server side code PHP for example.

I don't know should I re-write it in PHP or there is a php module or library which can handle JS.

So practically is it possible ?

Comment: As you said, One is Client Side and other is Server Side. The client side gets executed after server side is done. You might want to check ajax, but you sill need a PHP code which would be called by ajax in background.

Comment: Without any specifics the general answer is, php and javascript don't usually do the same things...thus without more context question doesn't make much sense

Answer (score 0):

Since there are very much commands on client side which access your gui elements or dom this makes no sense.

If you only have Business logic in your code (calculations, string conversion, ie stuff that makes sense on server side) you should be able to convert it very easy by hand. I did it some times before.

As far as i know there is no automatic coverter which could do the work for you.